# Voip notification did not receive when app kill or terminated in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, pushkit

in my app,
it's the existing functionality of VoIP calls. some user report to me that don't receive VoIP calls. after I check so found that the reported user version is ios 13 or later.

but one my friend have iPhone 6 plus (ios 12.5) in that I received VoIP calls.

there are any settings that remain for ios 13 or later.

here is my code:

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
let provider1 = CXProvider(configuration: defaultConfig())
          provider1.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
           let update = CXCallUpdate()
           update.supportsDTMF = true
           update.supportsHolding = true
           update.supportsGrouping = false
           update.supportsUngrouping = false
           update.hasVideo = false
  //  self.provider = provider1
           let bgTaskID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()) {
           UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTaskID)
           }
          uuidneww = UUID()
           update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Calling")
    provider1.reportNewIncomingCall(with:uuidneww , update: update, completion: { error in })
}
```

Comment: Are you using callkit for your voip?  In iOS 13 and later you must call `reportNewIncomingCall` after receiving a VoIP push or your app will be terminated and no further voip pushes will be received.

Comment: @Paulw11 my app is terminated and no VoIP notification not received.

Comment: You explained that, but you didn't answer my question; there are changes in iOS 13; you must report an incoming voip call using callkit in response to a voip push

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I use Callkit for VoIP and also use "reportNewIncomingCall" after call

Comment: Then you should [edit] your question to show the relevant code

Comment: @Paulw11 check now

Comment: @mihirpipermitwala
i am facing same issue so have you found any solution then please tell me.

Comment: @shraddhakvaishanani not yet

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 15:**

If there's a push in foreground/background but there's no push in terminated state, and you fire CallKit API's be sure that:

1. `PKPushRegistry` object is created in `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`. This step is very important, coz you may create it within some view controller and of course it won't be called in background.
2. `delegate` is set
3. `pushRegistry:didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:forType:withCompletionHandler:` delegate method is called. Be sure to use the method with completion block, thus it still works it may not in the future